# SQL Injection por meio da url

Tags: php, mysqli

No momento meu site esta como www.site.com.br/blablabla_id_**2** para a definição de páginas.

Utilizo o mysqli para fazer pesquisas no banco de dados com esse id.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM post WHERE id_post = '$id'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){

    header("Location: 404.php");

}else{

    //Resto do código

}
```

Terei algum problema com sql injection?

Comment: Sim vai ter problema, não basta trocar o driver mysql_* pelo mysqli é preciso tratar as entradas do form e usar prepared statements. [Aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3864/91) tem outras informações sobre sql injection

Comment: Uma boa prática é pegar o seu código em um ambiente "caixa de areia" e tentar hackear ele. Veja se você consegue fazer algo do tipo tentar acessar a URL "www.site.com.br/blablabla_id_2'--DROP TABLE (coloca o nome de uma tabela aqui)"

Comment: Agradeço. Testei em meu código e o drop table não funcionou, assim como outras funções. Obrigado pela ajuda, vou ler as melhores práticas para não me arrepender depois.

Comment: Não precisa de nada de mirabolante, basta usar `$id = mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['id'] );` e fazer isso em todos os parâmetros que já resolve o problema do injection. Depois, para o código ficar mais elegante, até pode usar _prepared statements_ se quiser, em vez do escaping. E se não pretende trocar de base de dados, melhor ficar no mysqli mesmo. Não tem necessidade  nenhuma de usar camadas intermediárias e simulação de recursos, como outras _libs_ da moda fazem. Lembrando que _prepared statements_ foram feitos para performance em _loops_, a proteção é só um "brinde".

Comment: @Bacco, Me permita discordar, mas [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) não resolve o problema. Alguns links bastante interessantes: [SQL injection that gets around mysql_real_escape_string()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) e [Why mysql_real_escape_string() isn’t enough to stop SQL injection attacks!](http://johnroach.info/2011/02/17/why-mysql_real_escape_string-isnt-enough-to-stop-sql-injection-attacks/)

Comment: @Marcio Você tem razão de que não resolve em todos os casos, mas nessa query específica da pergunta resolve sim. Parâmetros numéricos requerem outro tipo de tratamento.

Comment: @MarcioSimao ok, digitei errado, era pra ser mysqli_ :) Mas gostei do link, pois lá também mostra que PDO não escapa do problema nem com prepared statements, pq sao emulados e vao sofrer o injection de qq jeito, bom pra alertar o pessoal que acha que é a melhor coisa do mundo. Ao menos podemos chegar num consenso: mysqli + prepared statements é o caminho mais seguro.

Comment: Pra quem não quiser ler o Q&A todo que o @MarcioSimao recomendou, segue o resumo: Pro `mysqli_real_escape_string()` ficar seguro, lembrem se-de usar `mysqli_set_charset()` antes, setando para um desses 3 parâmetros: `utf8`, `latin1` ou `ascii`, senão alguns caracteres especiais podem "vazar" e ainda permitir algum ataque (se bem que o bug apontado é pra `mysql` e não `mysqli`, mas não custa nada fazer certo).

Comment: @bfavaretto, O problema é que uma aplicação, por menor que seja, dificilmente vai girar em torno de apenas uma query, então é melhor adotar técnicas que fechem a maior quantidade de brechas possíveis.

Comment: @Bacco, Para os usuário de MySQL é um caminho legal, mas é bom sempre buscar soluções mais abrangentes. Se amanhã ele for trabalhar com PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server ou qualquer outro banco, acredito que a chave é nunca confiar nas entradas, para isso o PHP já disponibiliza excelentes sanitizadores, aliando isso ao uso de PDO, a aplicação vai obter um bom grau de segurança. O PDO tem a vantagem também abstrair a comunicação com o banco, então para qualquer banco, os métodos são os mesmos.

Comment: Eu li o Q&A indicado, e o que diz lá é o oposto. O PDO simula os _prepared statements_, portanto com PDO você tem o bug com e sem PS. Fora isso, não posso falar pelos outros, mas eu particularmente sempre prefiro usar camada nativa do que essas máscaras de compatibilidade (assim como usar JQuery pra coisa que se resolve com JS, por exemplo). Mas entendo perfeitamente que cada um sabe o que faz de melhor com a experiência que tem. Eu sei que provavelmente nunca vou precisar de PDO pra nada, mas respeito quem prefere. Só não consigo imaginar que essa coisa de trocar de banco sempre seja normal.

Comment: @Bacco, Minha interpretação foi diferente, não vi lá oposto do que estou dizendo, na verdade o que disse é algo universal. Sobre o PS, isso não pode ser chamado de bug, mas sim vulnerabilidade. Além disso, é algo bem simples ativar os _prepared statements_ de forma nativa no PDO. Sobre o banco, em nenhum momento falei em trocar, o que falei foi que hoje é possível que um bom desenvolvedor tenha que trabalhar com mais de um banco, nesse momento o PDO vai ser uma mão na roda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Juntando o que eu já havia comentado com o Q&A apontado pelo Marcio, segue uma modificação que resolve o problema nas primeiras duas linhas de código, economizando uma camada de aplicação desnecessária para o caso em questão:

```
mysqli_set_charset( 'utf8' );                   // pode usar 'latin1' ou 'ascii'
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string( $_GET['id'] ); // aqui estamos 100% sanitizados.

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM post WHERE id_post = '$id'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){
    header("Location: 404.php");
}else{
    //Resto do código
}
```

**Notas:**

- A primeira linha é extremamente importante para evitar uma vulnerabilidade que permite certos caracteres escaparem da sanitização. Setando a página correta, a interpretação do *escape* funciona como esperado.
- Na segunda linha fazemos a sanitização propriamente dita.
- Importante notar que apesar de você estar trabalhando com dados numéricos, não removi as aspas da sua *query* propositalmente, como uma proteção extra. Se preferir, pode removê-las, mas forçando algo no sentido do `$id` ser mesmo numérico (somando com zero, por exemplo).

Comment: Agradeço a colaboração de todos. Acho que vou ficar com esse código que mais se assemelha ao meu. Obrigado! Espero que evite mesmo os sql injections!

Answer (score 3):

Seu código está totalmente vulnerável a SQL injection, para prevenir invasões você pode utilizar dois recursos bastante úteis, os [filtros de entrada](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php) e o [PDO](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php) para que sua query seja parametrizada.

Seu código com a utilização destes recursos se torna:

```
$id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

// Depois de criar o objeto PDO com o driver do seu banco de dados, utilize o código abaixo

$Ps = $Pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM post WHERE id_post = :id');

$Ps->execute([':id', $id]);

if ($Ps->rowCount() == 0) {
    header('Location: 404.php');
    die();
} else {
    // Pelo menos um registro foi localizado
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Eu faria conforme o marcio Simao propôs, usando PDO, mas se no seu caso for complexo mudar todo o codigo de mysqli para PDO, segue abaixo, uma alternativa:

```
    <?php 
    class DB{
        private $conn;

        public function getConnection(){
            $this->conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "mvc");
        }
        public function execReader($SQL){
            return $this->conn->query($SQL);
        }            
    }

    $id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id = ".  addslashes($id);

    $DB = new DB();
    $DB->getConnection();
    $query = $DB->execReader($SQL);
    if ($query == 0) {
        header('Location: 404.php');
        exit();
    }

    $vo = new ProdutoVO();
    while($reg = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $vo->setId($reg["id"]);
        $vo->setNome($reg["nome"]);
        $vo->setMarca($reg["marca"]);
        $vo->setPreco($reg["preco"]);
    }

    var_dump($vo);
    ?>
```

Comment: tirei 3 linhas em branco do seu código pra não aparecer barra de scroll e caber tudo na tela de uma vez. Se achar que não ficou bom, fique à vontade para reverter a edição.

Answer (score 2):

Amigo, para resolver esse problema e facilitar sua vida em relação a consultas em banco de dados dentre outras diversas funções, tente utilizar o "PDO PHP", um exemplo que resolveria seu problema seria esse:

```
prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);

// insert one row
$name = 'one';
$value = 1;
$stmt->execute();

// insert another row with different values
$name = 'two';
$value = 2;
$stmt->execute();
?>
```

Dê uma olhada na documentação do [Prepared Statements PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.prepared-statements.php)
e na do [PDO](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php)

Comment: As formas de passagem de parâmetro descritas nos cometários `// insert one row` e `// insert another row with different values` estão erradas, [dê uma revisada na documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.bindparam.php)